# How do I set right alignment in a longtable column with a fixed width?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

How do I set right alignment in a `longtable` column with a fixed width?

I have `\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{8cm}}`

and I'd like my first column to be aligned on the right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can define a new column as

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{6cm}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{Rp{8cm}}\toprule
 col1 & col2 \\\midrule
 \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]  \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS. The package `booktabs` is used to get beautiful rules instead of `\hline`.