# Right aligning two columns next to each other in longtable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable

Reading [this other thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66123/how-do-i-set-right-alignment-in-a-longtable-column-with-a-fixed-width), I found how to right align a column in longtable. However if I want to right align two columns that are next to each other:

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{6cm}|}                                                                                                                                                              
%                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                                                     
\begin{longtable}{|p{9.32cm}|R{5.97cm}|R{3.14cm}|p{4.57cm}|}
```

Ends up with columns alignments mixed up, but not the way I want (1st and last left ligned, the other two right aligned)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define another column type for the other alignment. Notice that I used an argument in the definitions, so you can use the desired widths (I changed the widths in my example so the table will fit in the page):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}                                                                                                                                                              
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}                                                                                                                                                              

\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                                                     

\begin{longtable}{|L{3.32cm}|R{3.97cm}|R{3.14cm}|L{3.57cm}|}
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment &
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment &
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment &
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Any chance to have headers centered, while rows left and right aligned?

Comment: @maraujop You're welcome! Regarding your question, you can use `\multicolumn` to override the column type specification for the headers: `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{header1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{header2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{header3} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{header4} \\ `.

Comment: Definitely you know Latex, thanks!! I was going nuts with this.

Comment: I've just realized that doing this breaks my seqsplit. Sometimes my column names are very long words. Thus columns extend to wrap those words and my column widths get all messed up, any hints? thanks

Comment: @maraujop No idea without some example of your actual code. Please, feel free to open a follow-up question. Make sure to include there a minimal working example showing the problem mentioned.

Comment: Yes, you are right, here is the follow-up http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119581/using-seqsplit-with-multicolumn thanks again.