# Using seqsplit with multicolumn

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to create a longtable with headers centered, columns left or right aligned. Thanks to my previous question:
[Right aligning two columns next to each other in longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119556/right-aligning-two-columns-next-to-each-other-in-longtable/119561) and its great answer, I've crafted this example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|L{3.32cm}|R{3.97cm}|R{3.14cm}|L{3.57cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ header1 } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{header2} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ \seqsplit{The\_header3\_is\_longer\_than\_expected} } & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{What\_would\_happen\_if\_header4} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment \\
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment \\
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment \\
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The problem with this, is that seqsplit is not doing its job and splitting long words when width set is reached. See:

[image: Latex example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `\multicolumn` because the columns are declared as `p` ones: use `\centering` and just remember to add `\arraybackslash` for the last one (or end the row with `\tabularnewline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % may come handy
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|L{3.32cm}|R{3.97cm}|R{3.14cm}|L{3.57cm}|}
\hline
\centering header1 &
  \centering header2 &
  \centering \seqsplit{The\_header3\_is\_longer\_than\_expected} & 
  \centering\arraybackslash \seqsplit{What\_would\_happen\_if\_header4} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment \\
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment \\
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment \\
some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment & some text goes here to illustrate the alignment \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with `seqsplit`.  You explicitly told `latex` that your header is a centered line (`c`).  It does what you asked.  You need to make your multicolumn type `p{...}` for `latex` to split it.

Comment: isn't latex able to center text multiline? no way to achieve something like this, centered in a specific width?

Comment: @maraujop: You can add `\centering`.