# Why cannot the word in the last column be centered

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
\centerline {image}
 &    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ABC} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{DEF} \\
\hline
 & \centering A&\centering B&\centering C&\centering D
 \\
\hline
\centerline 1&&&& \\
\hline
\centerline 1&&&& \\
\hline
\centerline 1&&&& \\
\hline
\centerline 1&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

When I try centering `D`, I have a problem in the shape of the table. Why is that? How can I center it appropriately?

Thanks.

Comment: This is very similar in nature to [How do I set right alignment in a `longtable` column with a fixed width?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66123/5764) Try also loading the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) and issue `\centering\arraybackslash`...

Comment: You can use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\ ` then it will work (`\centering` redefines `\\ ` and breaks its table use.) don't use `\centerline` in LaTeX.

Comment: or maybe `{\centering D}`? (Not tested)

Comment: @alexis no justifcation command such as `\centering` or `\raggedright` has any effect if the end of paragraph is not in the scope of the command.

Comment: Right... even inside a table cell. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 8):

Don't use the PlainTeX `\centerline` macro in a LaTeX document.

If the contents of every single column should be typeset centered, it's better to define column types that do so automatically, without the user having to type lots and lots of `\centering` instructions. This idea is implemented in the example below.

By the way, the user guide of the `array` package explains that there are some deep deep reasons for why ordinary `\centering` instructions need not work always correctly in the final column of a table. The package also suggests a workaround, which involves providing the instruction `\arraybackslash`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
\newcolumntype{V}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|U|V|V|V|V|}
\hline
image & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ABC} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{DEF} \\
\cline{2-5}
 &  A& B& C& D \\
\hline
 1&&&& \\
\hline
 1&&&& \\
\hline
 1&&&& \\
\hline
 1&&&& \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `array` package would enable you to simplify the markup a bit, nut you can do

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
\centering {image}
 &    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ABC} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{DEF} \tabularnewline
\hline
 & \centering A&\centering B&\centering C&\centering D
 \tabularnewline
\hline
\centering 1&&&& \tabularnewline
\hline
\centering 1&&&& \tabularnewline
\hline
\centering 1&&&& \tabularnewline
\hline
\centering 1&&&& \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

`\tabularnewline` and `\\` normally mean the same thing in tables, but `\tabularnewline` is there even when `\centering` redefines `\\` (and it was added for that reason).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `\multicolumn`, why not to use it for centering? And no `\centerline`'s! They mean centered lines, so using them inside a tabular is strange.

A version without additional packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
\hline
%\centerline {image}
\centering image
 &    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ABC} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{DEF} \\
\hline
& \centering A&\centering B&\centering C& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ D} \\
\hline
%\centerline 1&&&& \\
\centering 1&&&& \\
\hline
%\centerline 1&&&& \\
\centering 1&&&& \\
\hline
%\centerline 1&&&& \\
\centering 1&&&& \\
\hline
%\centerline 1&&&& \\
\centering 1&&& &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]